# C/C++ PNG library for creating polygons

Tags: c++, c, png

Is there a good C/C++ library for creating PNG files and that supports colored polygons and shapes? This library should be OS independent, since I need it for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: This library should be OS independent. I need it for both Linux/Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) library meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a cross-platform Computer Vision framework that supports several image formats, including PNG.

[Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is a cross-platform library for building graphical interfaces, and it may provide what you are looking for through [QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files).

[DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) is a smaller cross-platform Image Library that also supports PNG.

Comment: Thanks. Only QT of these support polygons, but is a huge library to download. I need a smaller library.

Comment: I think OpenCV offers some support as well. Check the [drawing functions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS...for Windows you may consider GDI+, it comes with a friendly C++ interface and it's more intuitive than GDI (even if performance are really poor). Moreover you can save in many different formats.

### Links

You can find some good example here:

[Converting a BMP Image to a PNG Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Graphics.DrawPolygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I want it as OS independent. so GDI doesn't help I think.

Comment: Then you may use the **QT Library**. I had to do something with it just once under Linux and _for what I remember_ it was great.
You may see: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Comment: But it is huge in size, it is not suitable for my small project.

Comment: You're right, if you have to use it only for that task it's...to much.

Answer (score 0):

To save as PNG, you can use [LibPNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), it's pretty good. To do the rendering, GDI / GDI+ can be used. (GDI+ is easier to use but is very slow, though, so you won't be able to use that in high-throughput applications.)